# how to check internet connection and stop the application with didFinishLaunchingWithOptions iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I'm still learning iOS , just i finish my first application but i want to add some function when the application running , here I'm using did finish launching with option method in appdelegate   , i want to change this code , first check if the user have internet or not if not show uialertView also , if there is no internet i need  a function can stop the application like

Alert ( this application need internet and you dont have internet right now pls try later ) and the application will exit . 
 or also in some case maybe the web service out of work

if possible explain me where i should put the if statement  and how i can exit the application

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
       [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];




        NSFileManager *fileManger=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);

        NSString *doumentDirectoryPath=[pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *destinationPath= [doumentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"istudentDatabase.plist"];




       // NSLog(@"plist path %@",destinationPath);

        //if Plist not exists will copy new one
        if ([fileManger fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]){


           NSLog(@"Settings File exists ");



        }else{
            // Copy New Plist 
            NSString *sourcePath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"istudentDatabase.plist"];

          [fileManger copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];





        }



        settingsClass * settings =[[settingsClass alloc]init];


        NSNumber * userid = [settings loadPlist:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid"]];

        if ([userid intValue] == 0)
        {
            //NSLog(@"You Dont Have USerid ");
            // Send a synchronous request
    NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fahads-macbook-pro.local/ios/newuser.php"]];
            NSURLResponse * response = nil;
            NSError * error = nil;
            NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                                  returningResponse:&response
                                                              error:&error];

            if (error == nil)
            {
    NSDictionary * mydata = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

                [settings saveNewUserId:[mydata[@"userid"] intValue]];

        NSLog(@"%@",mydata[@"userid"]);

            }else{
                NSLog(@"Error please Check Your Connections ");

            }


        }else{


            NSLog(@"You Have Userid : %@",userid);

        }


        NSMutableDictionary * itemsPlist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:destinationPath];
        NSLog(@"Items : %@",itemsPlist);


        return YES;
    }
```

**also if there is no way to exit the application , i have view controller  and on this view controller there is push button i want to hide this button  from appdelegate with If statement for example if no connection hide the start button and show some hint there is no connection.**

thanks advance

Comment: You can't stop an app from launching / exit an app. Its not possible.

Comment: so what i can do on this case ? my application working with web service if  web service not available  or there is an problem with internet connection , how i can solve this issue ?

Comment: @Mr.Geeker maybe put some nice view that will say "Please Connect to the internet" also you can add some pull to refresh component if the user connected after he lunched so he can pull to refresh and lunch the app as intendent

Comment: You can exit an app - `exit(0)` but I wouldn't do it that way. That's not iOS way. To check if there is an internet connection and whether host is reachable you can use https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Using exit(0) would get your app rejected from the app store. Just pop up a dialog telling the user there is no internet, there's no need to add a pulldown to refresh if you check for connectivity / attempt to make a connection each time the app comes to the foreground because if the user has disabled connectivity they need to switch away from your app to turn it back on. Then if they return to your app you will have the chance to perform a network activity again in appBecameActive.

Comment: @Roma-MT this what i want if you can explain what i should change with my code . thanks  other who trying to helping me .

Comment: The Reachability API will tell your app when connectivity has resumed if it is disrupted, so your app can retry a network connection automatically. So there's *no need* for the user to pull down and refresh connectivity, unless you specifically want them to do that for some reason.

Comment: @MartinH I have done it in my app because that what a customer would , I actually find it nice :) , however I wrote it as a suggestion (I didn't say it is a must). IMO it is nice to let user to feel that he has some control over something ... like a dialog idk how to explain it.

Comment: @Mr.Geeker initially I would put the 'activityIndicator' to make some smooth and nice animation while you perform the connectivity checks.
If there is no connection or server is not reachable put appropriate view with some picture that says no internet connection/host is not reachable and make this view respond to pull to refresh if you want this behavior , or retry the connection until it is ok and keep running.

Comment: Do both. Reachability's notifications are useful because they tell you when to retry because the device's network connection is now working. User-requested retry (such as pull-to-refresh) is useful when the device's network connection is working but some error elsewhere on the Internet broke the connection. Reachability can't tell you about the server itself or the rest of the network in between.